# getting response when using AXFetchAsSregTransform behavior in dotnetopenauth

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

I am using `AXFetchAsSregTransform` behavior in DotNetOpenAuth and thereafter using

```
ClaimsRequest( Email = DemandLevel.Request,
                FullName = DemandLevel.Request)
```

I am using

```
var claimsResponse = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
```

to receive response.  It's working fine with Google, but in case of AOL, MyOpenID it is returning null.  How should solve this problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could [include logs](http://tinyurl.com/dnoalogs).